# Java immediately instantiated class

Tags: java

Can someone please explain to me how this code works? Specifically, the `new Comparator` part? It looks like a class definition that's being immediately instantiated. Thank you.

```java
// Make a List of all anagram groups above size threshold.
List<List<String>> winners = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
for (List<String> l : m.values())
    if (l.size() >= minGroupSize)
        winners.add(l);

// Sort anagram groups according to size
Collections.sort(winners, new Comparator<List<String>>() {
    public int compare(List<String> o1, List<String> o2) {
        return o2.size() - o1.size();
    }});

// Print anagram groups.
for (List<String> l : winners)
    System.out.println(l.size() + ": " + l);
```

Comment: [Anonymous Classes - The Java™ Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html)

Comment: Oh, and the more modern way to write that would be `Collections.sort(winners, Comparator.comparing(List::size));`

Comment: this is not the result the above code expects.  this default behavior will cause the minimum sized List put in the front.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch `Comparator.comparingInt(List::size)` would be right.

Comment: Did you really test between:
Collections.sort(winners, new Comparator<List<String>>() {
    public int compare(List<String> o1, List<String> o2) {
        return o2.size() - o1.size();
    }});
and:
Comparator.comparingInt(List::size)